# how to hook prerender video with MobileVLCKit on iOS

Tags: swift, objective-c, vlc, libvlc

I want to hook realtime video data to get realtime base64 image from an video play by MobileVLCKit.

I researched about this and get this: https://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_to_memory_(smem)_tutorial/
https://gist.github.com/TimSC/4121862

But I don't know how to use this using Objective-c or Swift.